# Is this a known technique or a custom technique?

Tags: cipher

I recently watched "A Good American," and I'm wondering what the decryption method is that he is using [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHI75kRtdZY&t=0m40s), or is it a custom decryption method? He slides an array of letters printed on paper over another array of letters printed on paper and marks the decrypted letters above the one on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a [one-time pad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) cipher.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be seeing a lot of detail in a shot that lasts maybe one second. 
From what I could **see**, he’s just decrypting a ciphertext, using a key. 
Or maybe encrypting a plaintext, using a key.

But, based on you *description*, it sounds a little like crib-dragging. 
In WWII, the German military based most of their communications
on the Enigma cipher machine. 
The Enigma had a design flaw: it would never encrypt a symbol to itself. 
The Allies would,
basically, guess at strings / phrases that might appear in a message
(i.e., that commonly appeared in many messages);
these guesses were called “cribs”. 
They would then drag (slide) these cribs across a German cipher text
looking for positions where no character matched.

For example, consider the ciphertext `QEWHLFOOTBARRS`,
and consider the crib `HEILHITLER`. 
The first ten characters of that ciphertext could not decrypt to `HEILHITLER`
because the second letter is an `E`.

```
QEWHLFOOTBARRS
HEILHITLER
 ↑
```

Neither could 2-11, 3-12, or 4-13 do it:

```
QEWHLFOOTBARRS                QEWHLFOOTBARRS                QEWHLFOOTBARRS
 HEILHITLER                     HEILHITLER                     HEILHITLER
    ↑                                 ↑                        ↑        ↑
```

but 5-14 *could* be `HEILHITLER`:

```
QEWHLFOOTBARRS
    HEILHITLER
```

because no letter encrypts to itself. 
These crib matches were potential partial decrypts that were instrumental
in decrypting the entire message.

Comment: OP tells us he "watched" the movie, but you "seem to be seeing a lot of detail in a shot that lasts maybe one second".

Comment: Yeah, there is more detail in the film.